# Tiny MCE inlinepopup do not generate its template

Tags: tinymce

I really wonder with tiny MCE. I have tried to googling but found nothing.
The issue is about inlinepopup dialog. For example when you click on image button, it will open oopup window.

The problem is, when i run it directly from file (NOT through http), the popup has nice frame, where i can see the title and close icon on the top right.
In this example, i access directly to: file://localhost/D:/wamp/www/wysiwyg/tinymce_elfinder/examples/custom_formats.html

But, with the same file, when i access tiny MCE from htto, the frame is gone. I access throuh: . It makes popup title cant be shown because it has white color and close icon do not appeart too. I can close thedow b winy moving my mouse until i reach the close icon on the top right.

To make it clear, you can see screenshot i attached here.
http://wiliatno.com/tinymce.jpg

Image with number 1 is when i accessing through http
Image with number 2 is wehn accessing throung direct file path.

Disable inliepopup plugin is not the wayout, because i do not want to use regular popup window which can be blocked by popup blocker.

take a look here http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php
and try to click on image icon, html icon, or anything that will show an inline popups. When inlinepopups show, it do not generate templates.html in /plugin/inlinepopups/ folder. So, you cant see the title and close button at that inline popup. At the top right corner, try to move your mouse slowly until it change to hand shapre and you can close inlinepopups from there. but the close icon do not shown clearly, because tinymce do not generate template.html's inlinepopups correctly.

But, if you open tinymce directly from Hard Drive, NOT using http, even there is an security alert from tinymce, templates.html for inlinepopups can be generates perfectly (like i have shown on my first post with screenshot).

So, what is the problem with tinymce? Why tinymce give inlinepopups plugin, but cant generate template.html inside plugin/inlinepopups correctly?

Please help me.
thanks.